# Angularjs Div Autorefresh

Tags: angularjs

How to auto refresh  DIV or span in angularjS ? what is write in angularjs for refresh

```
        <div class="direct-chat-text">
                  <div ng-repeat="comment in comments">
                    <div class="updates">
                    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
                        <span>{{comment.message}}</span>
                    </div>
```

Comment: just refresh the model, the view will update automatically

Comment: Why do you have controller defined inside `ng-repeat`?

Answer (score 1):

Controller should be defined earlier, values changing in model will change in the view as well.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div class="direct-chat-text">
        <div ng-repeat="comment in comments">
            <div class="updates">
                <span>{{comment.message}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you have to update scope data of "comments" and then your view will be updated with new data. to update data you can use $timeout with collback